# Check if a String is a digit without converting it to number

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a string is "0", "1", "2", ... , "9" without converting the string to a number. Any suggestions? Right now I'm doing a .equals( ) for each and it's ugly.

Comment: You mean if it's a single digit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to 
 do this. The pattern `\d` should work, it means match a single digit. In Java you have to escape the backslash so it becomes `\\d`.

```
String str = "4";

str.matches("\\d"); // true
```

Comment: And what about if I wanted to match the string to a +, -, or *  ? What's the proper way to do a whitelist of single digit strings?

Comment: If you want to match a digit or any of those, you can use a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) where you specify each of the characters. So for example, you could use this regex: `str.matches("[\\d\\+\\-\\*]");`. Making sure to escape the characters +,-, and *.

Comment: Last question, if I want to match a string of length two, would I do it the same way? e.g. str.matched("[\\+\\==\\-\") Thanks for the help so far

Comment: One way to do that would be to first check that `str.length() == 2`. Or you could modify the regex to: `str.matches("[\\d\\+\\-\\*]{2}");`. You can specify how many of the characters from the character class to match in braces, using [this notation](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#iteration).

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
if (text.length() == 1 && text.charAt(0) >= '0' && text.charAt(0) <= '9')
```

Or create a `HashSet<String>` with every value you want, and use `contains`.

Answer (score 3):

borrowing Jon's method and using builtins.

```
if (str.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
someString.length() == 1  &&  "0123456789".contains(someString)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char ch = "4";
boolean answer = Character.isDigit(ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
if ("7".matches("^[0-9]$")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you're interested:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils;

String str = "6";

(str.length() == 1 && NumberUtils.isNumber(str)); // true
```